# finding HTML tags with python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have a HTML file and I want to find out the `<tr>` tags whose id begins with "tr" like `"id=tr3245"`, `"id=tr8796"` etc.

```
<tr id=tr1256>
  ....
</tr>
<tr id=tr5847>
  ....
</tr>
<tr id=tr8746>
  ....
</tr>
<tr id=tr9844>
  ....
</tr>
```

How can I do this with "beautiful soup"?

Answer (score 2):

Use `BeautifulSoup.select` with `tr[id^="tr"]` css selector (See [Beautiful Soup Documentation - CSS Selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<tr id=tr1256>
  ....
</tr>
<tr id=tr5847>
  ....
</tr>
<tr id=tr8746>
  ....
</tr>
<tr id=tr9844>
  ....
</tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for tr in soup.select('tr[id^="tr"]'):
    print(tr.get('id'))
```

prints

```
tr1256
tr5847
tr8746
tr9844
```